# Generating two rows from one source row

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a table which has columns:

- `txn_id`
- `from_user_id`
- `to_user_id`
- `price`

I want a query that produces two rows for each source row. The output would look like:

- `focal_user_id` (new)
- `txn_id`
- `from_user_id`
- `to_user_id`
- `price`

The `focal_user_id` value is generated from `from_user_id` for the first row output, and generated from `to_user_id` for the second row.

I need to do this in SQL rather than code because then I can make use of `WHERE` and `LIMIT`, as well as do some joins based on the new `focal_user_id` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I completely destroy the question in my head this is what you meant by two rows out of each one:

```
create table #TableOne (
    TxnId int, 
    FromUserId int, 
    ToUserId int, 
    Price decimal(5,2)) ;

insert into #TableOne values 
    (1, 1, 2, 100.01),
    (2, 1, 2, 100.01),
    (3, 2, 1, 100.01),
    (4, 2, 1, 100.01),
    (5, 3, 4, 100.01),
    (6, 4, 3, 100.01),
    (7, 4, 3, 100.01) ;

select 
    FromUserId AS FocalUserId,
    TxnId,
    FromUserId,
    ToUserId,
    Price
from #TableOne 
union all 
select 
    ToUserId AS FocalUserId,
    TxnId,
    FromUserId,
    ToUserId,
    Price
from #TableOne ;
```

Alternatively, using `APPLY` (lateral join):

```
SELECT
    CA.FocalUserId,
    TON.TxnId,
    TON.FromUserId,
    TON.ToUserId,
    TON.Price 
FROM #TableOne AS TON
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES 
        (TON.FromUserId), 
        (TON.ToUserId)
) AS CA (FocalUserId);
```